# Generate random string using javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code within the `<script>` tags, which are within the `<head>` tags of my HTML file;

```
function generateUMR($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Within the `<body>` tags, I have the following line of code in order to output the randomly generated string;

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> generateUMR(); </script>';
```

I have been trying for a few hours now but I am receiving no output from this code, yet no errors, could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In javascript string concatenations is done with + operator, not with . like in php. it should be `$randomString += ...`. also consider declaring the variables with `var $characters`. If you don't do the variables will go to the global scope which could cause troubles in the future.

Comment: @IgorMalyk: That code block is php. (`strlen($characters)` and the dollar-sign variables are a big hint)

Comment: So how do you call a function in PHP from javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a string of 5 random characters in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is treated as a string, you need to concatenate the function call like so.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ' . generateUMR() . ' </script>';
```

In order to see the result in the browser, you will need to view the HTML source because the browser won't show the content of a script tag. It doesn't really make sense to output this into a script tag, because it's just a random string, try some other tag such as `<p></p>` instead.

If you are trying to call the PHP function from the client side, then that won't work. You'll need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) to do that.

Comment: I altered my code as you suggested but still no output :(

Comment: ... and no one noticed that `generateUMR` is a PHP function... `:)`

Comment: @user3266484 what kind of output are you expecting? your PHP function will just output a random string, no JS logic...

Comment: For some reason I can't comment on Reinder Wits comment below, but when I tried his suggestion I got this error - Fatal error: Call to undefined function generateUMR(), any ideas? Thanks for ye're help so far anyway..

Comment: I just want it to output the random string so that I can ensure it is working before using in it my furthur code..but it seems the function is outputting nothing?

Comment: that is because javascript has no idea of you server side PHP functions

Comment: @user3266484 it looks like your function is out of scope from when the echo is calling it. Is the function in an include or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry I had placed the code within the script tags rather than in the PHP block, when I moved it down it works now, thanks a million for ye're help, my javascript skills are not great as you can probably tell, but I am improving with ye're help! :)